# jenkins integration with artifactory 5.5.2

Tags: jenkins

Currently I am using JFrog OSS version 5.5.2 for my artifacts which is integrated with Jenkins version 2.19.4. The artifactory plugin version is 2.13.1. I created a free-style software project. The repository type is “generic-local”. I am able to run build successfully and builds are saved in repository but the artifacts are not saved.Also, there is no option called “deploy artifacts to artifactory” in Jenkins configuration.

Do I have change my settings or update Jenkins?

Please advice me what changes has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to upgrade jenkins?

No: the [Artifactory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) requires a Jenkins Core 1.521.

But you would need to define a Maven 2/3 build instead.

[image]

> ### Maven 3 Support for Jenkins Free-style Jobs
>
> The Jenkins Artifactory plugin supports running Maven 3 builds from free-style jobs by using a Maven 3 build step + a build environment section for the Artifactory Maven 3 integration (artifact and build information deployment).
> **For Maven 3 builds users are encouraged to configure the Artifactory integration using Jenkins' native Maven 2/3 build projects**.